# Passing numeric data containing < or > django to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django

am having a problem with char inside numeric data, it's too large to be cleaned. anyways.
I want to replace < and > from value.
just posting relevant codes.
views.py

```
def search_result(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        ChemSearched = request.POST.get('ChemSearched')
        tarname = BINDLL.objects.filter(targetnameassignedbycuratorordatasource__contains=ChemSearched).exclude(ki_nm__isnull=True)[:120]
        
        return render(request, 'Search/search_result.html',{'ChemSearched':ChemSearched,'tarname':tarname})
```

Html side

```
<script>
     data=[{% for Bindll in tarname %} {
                group: '{{ Bindll.targetnameassignedbycuratorordatasource }}',
                     variable:'{{ Bindll.zincidofligand}}',
                     value: {{Bindll.ki_nm|safe}}
                    }, {% endfor %}];
```

which is used by graph d3.js.
all go well unless I have '<' or '>' in value I'll have this result

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'
or if use escape value: {{Bindll.ki_nm|escape}}
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&lt'
any function to be used in Html side javascript to replace char or anything and keep only numeric like regex replace.
thanks.

Comment: Use JSON.stringify() instead of manually building the array in a for loop. Or create a Python route that sends backs JSON and use d3's loading mechanims to request it from the server. (to be clear: your issue is a side effect of a bad approach, and the solution is to change the approach, not to fix symptoms)

Comment: @ChrisG any docs or links to fix building the data in frontend in better way thanks

Comment: try `strip('<')` or `strip('>')`  it should be useful , and maybe you will need to parse it to `Int` to get rid of the string type